# Codename One Local Unittesting

Tags: java, codenameone

I evaluate Codename One but by what I got is, I can run it in the local emulator but I can not issue unit testing beside writing my own adapter or use Sikuli or maybe the AWT / Swing robot or something similar.

Does anyone have an idea how to use the simulator for unit testing? I would like being able to run the app in different simulators (sizes) and do ordinary unit testing.

I do not even know if I can have access to its source code, since the simulator is Swing it should be possible to emulate the simulator at a certain level.

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit tests to run locally and even use a test recorder tool, see:

http://www.codenameone.com/blog/test-it.html